# Cannot retrieve email from facebook using swift 3 and ios 10

Tags: facebook, swift3, ios10

Hello i am trying to retrieve my email from facebook as i am playing the facebook ios sdk using swift. IOS platform is 10, swift 3 and Xcode 8. I followed tutorials online but having trouble retrieving email.

below is my code:

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.current() == nil {
            print("I got token")
            let fbButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
            fbButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
            view.addSubview(fbButton)
            fbButton.center = view.center
            fbButton.delegate = self
            self.fetchprofile()
        }

        else {
            print("Dont have token")
            let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
            self.view.addSubview(loginView)
            loginView.center = self.view.center
            loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
            loginView.delegate = self
        }

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        if error != nil {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        print("I'm in")
        fetchprofile()
    }

func fetchprofile() {

        print("Getting profile")

        let parameters = ["fields": "email"]

        let graphRequest:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters, httpMethod: "GET")

        graphRequest.start(completionHandler: {(connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print("Error retrieving details: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let result = result as? [String:[AnyObject]], let email = result["email"] else {
                return
            }
            print("Email: \(email)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        })
    }
```

and in my appdelegate.swift file :

```
 //have both google and facebook signin. Google works but facebook doesn't
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                    sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
                                                    annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]) ||
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }
```

I am able to log in and log out but not able to retrieve email.

***UPDATE*** Actually when i actually pass print(email) i can see it on the console as an optional statement. I'm having trouble displaying it without optional statment

Comment: Did the user grant the email permission to the app? Does the user have a verified email address?

Comment: @WizKid actually i can see the email id but its optional i think my problem comes from printing it out. Having problem with the guard statement

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @Carlo where you able to solve the problem

Comment: @user3497437 I have solved the problem. Look my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have solved the problem in this way:

```
func fetchProfile(){
     FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields" : "email, name, id, gender"])
        .start(completionHandler:  { (connection, result, error) in
            guard let result = result as? NSDictionary, let email = result["email"] as? String,
                let user_name = result["name"] as? String,
                let user_gender = result["gender"] as? String,
                let user_id_fb = result["id"]  as? String else {
                    return
            }         
        })

    }
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply and thanks. I have been out and about for a few days. Again thanks for the response. Still very new to swift and picking up a lot

Comment: This worked perfectly. Guard can be quite confusing but makes sense once you read up on it. Worked for me on Swift 3, Xcode 8. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked well for me without the "/" in the graphPath parameter!
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me" .....